# How to use webdriver as context manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to use `ChromeDriver` within with block to make the code look better and get rid of using `driver.quit()` command in the end. However, It doesn't seem to work. As soon as the browser opens, it throws the following error. Perhaps, I doing something wrong. Ain't there any way to do so? Thanks in advance.

This is what I've tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver

with webdriver.Chrome() as wd:
    res = wd.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/')
    print(res.page_source)

#Another failure attempt with the same error

with webdriver.Chrome() as wd:
    wd.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/')
    print(wd.page_source)
```

This is the error I'm having:

```
    with webdriver.Chrome() as wd:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Comment: You are trying to use `webdriver.Chrome()` as context manager while it is not a context manager. You can check [this](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html#implementing-context-manager-as-a-class) to get info about how to implement your own context manager

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try below solution and let me know in case it's not what you want:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class WebDriver:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.driver

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.driver.quit()


with WebDriver(webdriver.Chrome()) as wd:
    wd.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/')
    print(wd.page_source)
```

Answer (score 33):

Now it's added to selenium ([SeleniumHQ/selenium#5919](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/5919)) so you can simply use the original approach from your question:

```
from selenium import webdriver

with webdriver.Chrome() as wd:
    res = wd.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/')
    print(res.page_source)
```