# Python - In case of an error occurs inside do

Tags: python, selenium

I am running a process with Selenium and handling as many errors as I can and creating custom exceptions for few, but I have an issue if unexpected error does occur within process Selenium will keep running and take up resources/ram unless explicitly shut down, is there a better way to handle it than wrapping everything around try except and within except shutting down Selenium? much thanks

I would like to have some kind of "signal" in case error occurs send error to sentry io and free ram space from Selenium

simple example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.example.com')
raise Exception()
```

if you dont explicitly say `driver.quit()` it will never shut down

dependinces https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/
https://pypi.org/project/selenium/

one more example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.test()

    def test(self):
        # Random unexpected error occurs
        # This case driver "doesnt" exist
        driver.get('https://www.example.com')

Example()
```

class is being ran from another file

I ended up doing this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

_driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

class Example:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.test()

    def test(self):
        # Random unexpected error occurs
        # This case driver "doesnt" exist
        driver.get('https://www.example.com')

try:
    Example(_driver)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    _driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you please provide us some code/input/output?

Comment: sure give me a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping everything in a `try`/`finally` or a `with` statement sounds like exactly the right thing to do here...

Since Selenium supports `with` statements directly, that's easiest:

```
from selenium import webdriver

with webdriver.Chrome() as wd:
    res = wd.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/')
    print(res.page_source)
```

(See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/54149666/683329)

The phrase to look for in documentation is "(use as a) context manager".

Otherwise, if you're working with something that either doesn't doesn't support the `with` statement, or you otherwise can't, you can do `try`/`finally`:

```
wd = with webdriver.Chrome()
try:
    res = wd.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/')
    print(res.page_source) 
finally:
    wd.quit()
```

**Edit:** If you're using a testing framework, it will have setup/cleanup functionality at module and class level and that cleanup will be run even if the tests fail.

Comment: If you have hundreds of lines of code, you probably have them in several functions anyway; have the setup and cleanup (using `with` or `try`/`finally`) in one function, which then calls the others. If there's an exception, it will propagate out of the function calls until it gets to the one that has the `with` or `try`/`finally`.

Comment: PS: If you're using a testing framework, it will have setup/cleanup functionality at module and class level and that cleanup will be run even if the tests fail.

Comment: thank you for example, it gave me an idea to run Selenium before Class pass driver to Class and in case expection happens inside Class to close Selenium