# How we can close the driver if we use return in conftest file

Tags: python, pytest

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="class")
def test_setup():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D://chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.maximize_window()

    return driver
```

Comment: Please post some explanation as well not just the code.

Comment: I would advise you to use context managers for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48630668/2681662

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it will close the window for you

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="class")
def test_setup():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D://chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.close()

    return driver
```

Comment: why would you close a `driver` before using it?

Answer (score 0):

The pytest documentation covers this
https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#teardown-cleanup-aka-fixture-finalization

> “Yield” fixtures yield instead of return. With these fixtures, we can
> run some code and pass an object back to the requesting fixture/test,
> just like with the other fixtures. The only differences are:
>
> return is swapped out for yield.
>
> Any teardown code for that fixture is placed after the yield.

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="class")
def test_setup():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D://chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.maximize_window()

    yield driver
    # teardown code
    driver.close()
```